# Populating a viewmodel from a database model but getting object reference error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, viewmodel

I had a similar problem with a dictionary - now I'm trying to populate a viewmodel, to return a JSON object to a GET request.

My viewmodel is:

```
public class HotelInventoryta
{
    public int api_version { get; set; }
    public string lang { get; set; }
    public List<Hotel_List_ta> hotels { get; set; }
}

public class Hotel_List_ta
{
    public int ta_id { get; set; }
    public string partner_id { get; set; }  
    public string name { get; set; }   
    public string street { get; set; }  
    public string city { get; set; }    
    public string postal_code { get; set; } 
    public string state { get; set; }   
    public string country { get; set; }
    public double latitude { get; set; }    
    public double longitude { get; set; }  
    public string desc { get; set; }    
    public string url { get; set; }    
    public string email { get; set; }  
    public string phone { get; set; }   
    public string fax { get; set; }     
}
```

My DataBase model is:

```
 [Table("tblHotel")]
public class Hotelta
{
    [Key()]
    [Column("hotel_id")]
    public long hotel_id { get; set; }
    public string hotel_name { get; set; }
    public string hotel_add1 { get; set; }
    public string hotel_towncity { get; set; }
    public string hotel_pc { get; set; }
    public string hotel_country { get; set; }
    public string hotel_pass { get; set; }
    public string hotel_email { get; set; }
    public string hotel_tel { get; set; }
    public string hotel_fax { get; set; }
}
```

My controller code to populate the viewmodel is:

```
    private HoteltaContext dbh = new HoteltaContext();
    //
    // GET: /ta/hotel_inventory
    [HttpGet]
    public HotelInventoryta hotel_inventory(int api_version, string lang)
    {
        {

            HotelInventoryta hotelinventory = new HotelInventoryta();
            hotelinventory.api_version = api_version;
            hotelinventory.lang = lang;

            // Get data from database
            var h = dbh.Hotelta.Where(x => x.hotel_id != 0).ToList();

            // loop through each result, and add it to the hotelinventory.hotels model
            foreach (var ht in h)
            {
                // I get the exception on the next line
                hotelinventory.hotels.Add(new Hotel_List_ta
                {
                    ta_id = 0,
                    partner_id = ht.hotel_id.ToString(),
                    name = ht.hotel_name,
                    street = ht.hotel_add1,
                    city = ht.hotel_towncity,
                    postal_code = ht.hotel_pc,
                    country = ht.hotel_country,
                    url = "http://www.me.com",
                    email = ht.hotel_email,
                    phone = ht.hotel_tel,
                    fax = ht.hotel_fax
                });
            }

            return hotelinventory;
        }
    }
```

The error is:

`Object reference not set to an instance of an object`

Firstly, can you help me resolve the error - and if possible, confirm if the way I am reading from the database and populating the viewmodel, is the best way to do it?

Thank you, Mark

Comment: I think it would be very helpful if you show the full stack trace. Or if you at least tell at which row the exception occurs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because the `hotels` property is never initialized. You could do this in the constructor of `HotelInventoryta`:

```
public class HotelInventoryta
{
    public HotelInventoryta()
    {
        hotels  = new List<Hotel_List_ta>();
    }

    // ...
}
```

Now you initialzed the property with an empty collection, so you can add items to it, rather than `hotels` being `null` which causes your exception.